# App title doesn't change after returning to previous fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I've been developing an android app which I included the default Navigation-Drawer from Android Studio and so on. In my home fragment, I've implemented CarViews, and then set those cardview(s) OnClickListener to replace the fragment with traditional procedure.
After the fragment replacement and new page comes, I wanted to change the Actionbar title.
So in the `onCreateView(...)` method, I tried,

```
((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setTitle("B");
```

It worked. But after pressing the hardware back button to go back to the stacked fragment, the title remains changed & it doesn't change to `"Home"` again. I've tried other ways. Here's my following codes. Thanks in advance.

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
        Objects.requireNonNull(((AppCompatActivity) Objects.requireNonNull(getActivity())).getSupportActionBar()).setTitle("Home");

        CardView cardView1 = root.findViewById(R.id.doctor_on);
        CardView cardView2 = root.findViewById(R.id.ambulance_e);
        CardView cardView3 = root.findViewById(R.id.maintainance_s);

        cardView1.setOnClickListener(this);
        cardView2.setOnClickListener(this);
        cardView3.setOnClickListener(this);

        return root;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        int id = v.getId();
        switch (id) {
            case R.id.doctor_on:
                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = Objects.requireNonNull(getActivity()).getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                Fragment fragment1 = new doctors();
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container1, fragment1).addToBackStack(getString(R.string.menu_home)).commit();
                return;
            case R.id.ambulance_e:
                //Put Actions
                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction2 = Objects.requireNonNull(getActivity()).getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                Fragment fragment2 = new ambulance();
                fragmentTransaction2.replace(R.id.container1, fragment2).addToBackStack(getString(R.string.menu_home)).commit();
                return;
            case R.id.maintainance_s:
                //Put Actions
                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction3 = Objects.requireNonNull(getActivity()).getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                Fragment fragment3 = new maintanance();
                fragmentTransaction3.replace(R.id.container1, fragment3).addToBackStack(getString(R.string.menu_home)).commit();
                return;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Home");
    }
}
```

To the next fragment(where I change the titlebar and pressed back button):

```
public class doctors extend Fragment{
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setTitle("B");
        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_doctors, container, false);

        return root;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And in the `doctors` Fragment... Should fix the title error.

```
@Override
public void onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView();
    Objects.requireNonNull(((AppCompatActivity) Objects.requireNonNull(getActivity()))
            .getSupportActionBar())
            .setTitle(getString(R.string.your_title_here));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to override the method onBackPressed() and write the code:

```
@Override
public View onBackPressed(){
    //Here goes the code that head back to your main fragment
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction3 = Objects.requireNonNull(getActivity()).getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            Fragment fragment3 = new maintanance();
            fragmentTransaction3.replace(R.id.container1, fragment3).addToBackStack(getString(R.string.menu_home)).commit();
}
```

}`

Answer (score 0):

Add below code in Home Fragment...

```
@Override
    public void onHiddenChanged(Boolean hidden) {
        super.onHiddenChanged(hidden);
        ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Home");
    }
```

Comment: Then please print log of all life cycle method and check with method is called when you are back from previous fragment

Comment: If you found your answer with my comment then kindly upvote comments so anybody comes to this page can easily get proper solution thanks .

Comment: @JaimilPatel Post answers as answer instead of a comment, please. Comments are not guaranteed to survive (they can be deleted at any moment) and other users won't look for answers in comments.